# Nesting tables in html with different padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following table:

[image]

---

I can't seem to get the inner table to be nested within the outer-table. Is table the right tool to use or is there some other tool that can let me do this kinds of things? I've read that I could use style and then manually position it based on the pixels, but that doesn't seem like a good solution..

Here's what I have (note: the inner table is the problem)

```
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>field_A </td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                            [optional]
                            <input type="text"> 
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            [optional]
                            <input type="text">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>field_D </td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'inner table', there's only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one table in your question. I think you want something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>field_A </td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <table style="position: relative; left: 25px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          [optional]
          <input type="text">
        </td>

        <td>
          [optional]
          <input type="text">
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            [optional]
            <input type="text">
          </td>

          <td>
            [optional]
            <input type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <tr>
      <td>field_D </td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This nests the table inside the other table, and indents it (based on the picture provided.)

Comment: Are you sure inserting a table as a table row is valid?